# SCons-Compiler error on Mac OS X regarding #include-ing files

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, scons

I am trying to compile [Geekinfo](http://code.google.com/p/geekinfo/) on Mac OS X 10.6.6 Snow Leopard. My config is:

- Xcode 3.2 with OSX 10.4 support
- Python 2.71
- SCons 2.01.

I also have Xcode 2.5 installed.

I checkout the latest svn repository

Then I ran *scons* in the the same directory. It should have compiled the library (as I have previously done successfully in Windows XP using MSVC 2008) but the output (in OSX) I got was:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: The build_dir keyword has been deprecated; use the variant_dir keyword instead.
File "/Users/muhammadumar/Desktop/gk/SConstruct", line 14, in <module>
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build.x86_32
o build.x86_32/src/geekinfo.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/geekinfo.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/basesystem.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/basesystem.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/smbios.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/smbios.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/system_old.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/system_old.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/x86processor.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/x86processor.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/glcontext.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/glcontext.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/gpu.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/gpu.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/Memory.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/Memory.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/Motherboard.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/Motherboard.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/OperatingSystem.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/OperatingSystem.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/Processor.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/Processor.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/System.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/System.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/macosxsystem.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/macosxsystem.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build.x86_32/src/macosxmodel.o -c -Wall -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -fasm-blocks -msse3 -O2 -arch i386 -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude -Ibuild.x86_32/include -Iinclude src/macosxmodel.cpp
sh: o: command not found
ar rc build.x86_32/libgeekinfo.a build.x86_32/src/basesystem.o build.x86_32/src/smbios.o build.x86_32/src/system_old.o build.x86_32/src/x86processor.o build.x86_32/src/glcontext.o build.x86_32/src/gpu.o build.x86_32/src/Memory.o build.x86_32/src/Motherboard.o build.x86_32/src/OperatingSystem.o build.x86_32/src/Processor.o build.x86_32/src/System.o build.x86_32/src/macosxsystem.o build.x86_32/src/macosxmodel.o
ar: build.x86_32/src/basesystem.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/smbios.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/system_old.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/x86processor.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/glcontext.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/gpu.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/Memory.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/Motherboard.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/OperatingSystem.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/Processor.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/System.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/macosxsystem.o: No such file or directory
ar: build.x86_32/src/macosxmodel.o: No such file or directory
scons: *** [build.x86_32/libgeekinfo.a] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

**I am unable to understand the above so please help me, or please provide me with the geekinfo binaries.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for visiting this thread but my problem is solved. scons did not work. i made a qmake config for the library and it compiled successfully. the test program works as well. Qt rocks!

Answer (score 1):

If it were make, then the problem would be that the 'CC' macro was defined as empty.  The command would look like '$(CC) -o ...' and the '-' would be interpreted by make as 'ignore errors from this command'.

Whether any of that translates to SCons, I'm not sure, but I'd start by worrying what the compiler is set to (or not set to).

Comment: actually the above happened after I messed up with the scons config makefile. I changed the CCFLAGS to CPPFLAGS since in the very first try the compiler said it couldnt find string, map vector headers (i.e. stdc++ headers!). I thought that the compiler was detecting my code as C not C++ (though all files were .cpp not .c) and invoking the C compiler instead. So I changed the scons flags and got the errors in the first post of this problem. Then I redownloaded the source(re-svn-checkout), but scons gave the same error as if it had a cache. It should have given the string not found error instead